# nodemon crash -- app crashed - waiting for file changes before startin

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Refer to the code below:

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.get('/', (req, res)=>res.status(200).send('hello world'));

app.listen(port, ()=>console.log(`Listening on localhost:${port}`));
```

and when I run with `nodemon server.js` It come with this error
[image]

Anything that I miss out ?

Comment: You using not using the CommonJS module system to import express. Change importing to `const express = require('express')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the `CommonJS` module importing system. If you want to use the ES6 module system, you have to setup Babbel.

Now to fix this issue use the `CommonJS` module importing system.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.get('/', (req, res)=>res.status(200).send('hello world'));

app.listen(port, ()=>console.log(`Listening on localhost:${port}`));
```